# Plotting vectors with different spacing

Tags: r

Have a list of vectors with different length (of which first value represents the start and last value represents the end).

```
A   1.1005  1.1084  1.177   1.2024  1.2085  1.1588  1.0868  1.1584  1.0892

B   1.079   1.1086  1.1741  1.184   1.118   1.1068  1.1655

C   1.1684  1.1693  1.2885  1.326   1.3069  1.2584  1.1163  1.1841

D   1.2462  1.1749  1.2304  1.2039  1.2162  1.2933  1.1998  1.1422
```

Tried to manually space them in excel to produce this plot in the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JjkF.jpg

Is there a way to plot the aggregate of n (beyond only 4 sets) number of theses values (with std dev) of these values on a graph (with y axis being values in the vectors, x axis being from start to end) using R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Sets up plot area tehn draws splines with the values at equally spaced intervals on a line by line basis:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,12), ylim=range(dat[-1],na.rm=TRUE) )
apply( dat[-1],1,function(x) lines(spline( x=seq(0,10,length=length(x[!is.na(x)])+1)[-1], 
                                           y=x[!is.na(x)])))
```

If you need the colors you can just save the values from the `spline` calls and plot with a for loop.

Comment: thank you! is it possible to merge and get the mean plot of all 4 lines?

Comment: Should be possible. I would switch to using `splinefun` so I can use the same x-values for all 4 series.